# Excel crashes after loading file

Tags: microsoft-excel

After loading a excel sheet excel crashes. 
No special errormessage in the screen.

If the same sheet is loaded on another computer it also crashes. 
Is there a program to repair this excel sheet ?

Comment: Please include the version of MS Office

Comment: " Is there a program to repair this excel sheet ? " - ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Excel has a built in repair feature you could try.  Open Excel then follow this menu path in Excel: File->Open.  Browse to the damaged file and select it in the File Open window.  Instead of pressing the Open button, select the Arrow on the right side of the Open button and select the "Open and Repair...” option.  Note: I have Excel 2003, hopefully your version of Excel includes the repair function.

Answer (score 1):

What fixed it for me, at least with one file where it happened, was to right click on the faulty file in the open dialog, and select "open as copy". (Office 365, version 1811)